# Unexpected error when deploying webapp on firebase

Tags: json, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I try to host my static Website on Firebase. I run through the tutorial on the official Firebase site.

I tried to deploy it, changed the firebase.json file, but nothing helped

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "public", 
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
  ]
}
```

this is my firebase.json file

this is the error message when I run firebase deploy:

```
mp@linux:~/Documents/Website/Codebytessoftware$ firebase deploy

Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Unexpected token ':' at 1:10
"hosting": {
         ^
File: "/home/mp/Documents/Website/Codebytessoftware/firebase.json"

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firebase.json is not a valid json file. Try this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public", 
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can check if your json file is valid json in [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: My bad, I messed up with the editor and missed the closing bracket of "hosting". I edited the answer, try now.

Comment: thanks :)
With your help I figured out the solution. you forgot the second }